# SSIS Package Failed in Production

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have got a SSIS Package running in a SQL Server. This Job is continuously failing in the Production.

I am getting the below error

[image: Error Screenshot]

Relevant error information from screenshot.

> SQL Server agent running a package in 64 bit mode. SQL Server 2016 SP2, CU17. The SQL command requires 4 parameters, buthte parameter mapping only has 0 parameters. The data flow source "Agreement Mapping" is an Excel Source which failed validation and returned validation status VS_ISBROKEN.

When I Manually run the Package in Visual Studio All the Nodes get executed.

Can someone help me to debug this error

I tried running the package Manually  in Visual Studio and i can see

All the Nodes got executed successfully.

Thanks!
Balaji

Comment: Using SSMS, right click on the job (Kantar_Automation_Files_Porting) and script to new window. Click the Edit link above and paste the definition into your question. That will tell me *how* you are running the package. When you run it manually and it works, *how* are you doing that and from what computer? Is it from within Visual Studio, the command line (if so, what is the specific command and arguments used)?

Comment: Do you have other SSIS packages on the server successfully consuming Excel files? Are they also running in 64 bit mode? i.e.: You may need to set the debugging property `Run64BitRuntime` to `False`.